# Write from R into template in excel while preserving formatting

Tags: excel, r

I have a dataframe's in R which want to write to excel (or csv) and to output in a nice format (e.g. with a border, title for the table, not starting from the cell A1).

At the moment I use the function write.table to write my dataframes into a csv file, and then I copy and paste my data into a document in excel where I have my tables ready formatted as template.

This is not a major issue when it is only one dataframe, but I now want to do it for multiple dataframes and have these across multiple tabs in excel.

Is there a way in which I can automatically copy my dataframes to specific cells in an existing excel spreadsheet with all the formatting correctly set?

Comment: CSV files are text-only.  You cannot include any formatting.  You can use [R (D)COM](http://cran.r-project.org/contrib/extra/dcom/) to write to and format Excel files from R.

Comment: @joran The question contains an important part : keeping the formatting of the original template. Go try that...

Comment: @JorisMeys Yeah, `?setStyleAction`.

Comment: @joran I know (see my answer). But if I have to downvote every question that can be answered by scrolling through quite some pages of manual, there wouldn't be many questions left. This is a perfectly valid question. It took a while of using XLConnect before I encountered that feature. It's not in the vignette, and very few help pages link to that specific information.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As Joran said, you have the [XLConnect](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/XLConnect/index.html) package. Read the [documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/XLConnect/XLConnect.pdf) or the [vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/XLConnect/vignettes/XLConnect.pdf) of that package carefully to know exactly what is possible.

Using XLConnect you normally overwrite the cell styles unless you set the style action to be "none" using

```
setStyleAction(wb,XLC$"STYLE_ACTION.NONE")
```

To set you on the right road, a trivial example :

```
require(XLConnect)
wb <- loadWorkbook("test.xlsx", create=TRUE)
setStyleAction(wb,XLC$"STYLE_ACTION.NONE")

Data <- data.frame(
  a = 1:10,
  b = letters[1:10]
)

writeWorksheet(wb,Data,"aSheet",startRow=1,startCol=1,header=TRUE)

saveWorkbook(wb)
```

Before

[image]

After

[image]

---

EDIT : As noted by Dirk Eddelbuettel, you can do the same using the `xlsx` package. I personally use `XLConnect` as it can handle both xls and xlsx, and seemed a lot more stable than any of the old packages I used for manipulating EXCEL files. I haven't used the `xlsx` package yet. You can take a look at the [CRAN page on Data Import/Export](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-data.html#Reading-Excel-spreadsheets) to know what is available.

Comment: FWIW the "xslx" package does that too.

Comment: Thanks joris, much appreciated!

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel; How do we do this in using xlsx package? I did not find any function that can save the formatting of an entire sheet from being preserved?

Comment: I've done quite a bit of writing from `R` to `.xlsx` files and prefer the `openxlsx` package much more than `xlsx`.  My reasoning is that I always had troubles getting my OS (64-bit) to work easily with `rjava` (a dependency of `xlsx`).  `openxlx` doesn't require `rJava` which made my life--at the time, at least--much easier.

Comment: openxlsx works great for 99% of the time but some 3rd party programs I use reject the openxlsx xlsx files and claim they cannot read the excel document. If I open the excel file, then save and retry it always works. Anyone know a workaround for this?

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel, how to do it in `xlsx` package?

Answer (score 2):

Some users were asking how to do it using the `xlsx` package.

There is a very good and extensive usage example of the `xlsx` package at [STHDA](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/r-xlsx-package-a-quick-start-guide-to-manipulate-excel-files-in-r).

It has examples for cell formatting, workbooks with multiple sheets, how to add figures, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a function that is based on `openxlsx` where you specify the workbook (`from_wb`) and sheet name/location (`from_sheet`) that has the styles and the workbook (`to_wb`) and sheet name/location (`to_sheet`) to which you want to transfer the style:

Note: I used the `purrr` and `glue` packages as well, but this could be re-written in base R.

```
copyStyle <- function(from_wb, to_wb, from_sheet, to_sheet) {
  # check for workbook objects
  if (!(inherits(from_wb, "Workbook") && inherits(to_wb, "Workbook"))) { 
    stop("from_wb and to_wb must be Workbook objects.")
    }
  
  # get all sheet names from workbooks
  from_sheets <- from_wb$sheet_names
  to_sheets <- to_wb$sheet_names

  # convert sheets from numeric to sheet name. wb$styleObjects uses sheet name
  if (is.numeric(from_sheet)) {
      from_sheet <- from_wb$getSheetName(from_sheet)
  }
  
  if (is.numeric(to_sheet)) { 
      to_sheet <- to_wb$getSheetName(to_sheet)
  }

  # if sheet name given check that it exists
  if (is.character(from_sheet) && !from_sheet %in% from_sheets) {
    stop(glue::glue("{from_sheet} was not found in from_wb"))
  }
  
  if (is.character(to_sheet) && !to_sheet %in% to_sheets) {
    stop(glue::glue("{to_sheet} was not found in to_wb"))
  }
  
  # get from_wb sheet styles
  from_styles <- purrr::keep(from_wb$styleObjects, ~ .x$sheet == from_sheet)

  # add styles to to_wb
  purrr::walk(from_styles, ~ openxlsx::addStyle(to_wb, 
                                                to_sheet, 
                                                .x$style, 
                                                rows = .x$rows, 
                                                cols = .x$cols))
  return(to_wb)
}
```

---

**Usage**

```
library(openxlsx)

wb <- loadWorkbook("getStyle.xlsx")

new_wb <- write.xlsx(head(iris), "transfer_style.xlsx")
# can give sheet name or index
copyStyle(from_wb = wb, to_wb = new_wb, from_sheet = "Sheet1", to_sheet = 1)

# must save workbook after copying style
saveWorkbook(new_wb, "transfer_style.xlsx", overwrite = T)
```

**Input**

`getStyles.xlsx` is a local Excel workbook with multiple styles on several sheets:

[image: getStyles.xlsx]

**Output**

`transfer_styles.xlsx`:

[image: transfer_styles.xlsx]