# Write out data to xlsx template in R without using XLConnect

Tags: r

I wanted to write out some data to xlsx file using a template xlsx file with pre-designed formatting.
I have already read the previous question: "Write from R into template in excel while preserving formatting". But the answer propose the use of XLConnect package which is not compatible with my environment as I am already using xlsx package. These two packages cannot be loaded at the same time due to the different Apache POI versions.

I wanted to ask what equivalent functions may exist outside the XLConnect package to `loadWorkbook` or `setStyleAction` which was mentioned as answer in the previous question as follows:

```
wb <- loadWorkbook("test.xlsx", create=TRUE)
setStyleAction(wb,XLC$"STYLE_ACTION.NONE")
```

Comment: There is a package called `xlsx` that uses similar syntax. I don't know of many other packages that allow you to write to excel files

Comment: The question you mentioned does mention (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11228942/write-from-r-into-template-in-excel-while-preserving-formatting#comment62387850_11229726) package `openxlsx` (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/openxlsx/versions/4.1.0/topics/addStyle)

Comment: I'll second- The `openxlsx` package is the most flexible that I've found to write to a file with formatting. Use `createStyle` and then `addStyle` to the wb. I changed my code so that I don't load any of the other xl-related packages.