# R / openxlsx / Finding the first non-empty cell in Excel file

Tags: r, openxlsx

I'm trying to write data to an existing Excel file from R, while preserving the formatting. I'm able to do so following the answer to this question ([Write from R into template in excel while preserving formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11228942/write-from-r-into-template-in-excel-while-preserving-formatting)), except that my file includes empty columns at the beginning, and so I cannot just begin to write data at cell A1.

As a solution I was hoping to be able to find the first non-empty cell, then start writing from there. If I run `read.xlsx(file="myfile.xlsx")` using the `openxlsx` package, the empty columns and rows are automatically removed, and only the data is left, so this doesn't work for me.

So I thought I would first load the worksheet using `wb <- loadWorkbook("file.xlsx")` so I have access to `getStyles(wb)` (which works). However, the subsequent command `getTables` returns `character(0)`, and `wb$tables` returns `NULL`. I can't figure out why this is? Am I right in that these variables would tell me the first non-empty cell?

I've tried manually removing the empty columns and rows preceding the data, straight in the Excel file, but that doesn't change things. Am I on the right path here or is there a different solution?

Comment: I started on something but it didn't work. What I can offer up is that by "table" they likely mean a Table object in Excel from INSERT >> Table in the ribbon.

Comment: Maybe [tidyxl](https://github.com/nacnudus/tidyxl) could be helpful here.

Comment: Yes! That's exactly it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by [Stéphane Laurent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1100107/st%C3%A9phane-laurent), the package `tidyxl` offers the perfect solution here.

For instance, I can now search the Excel file for a character value, like my variable names of interest ("Item", "Score", and "Mean", which correspond to the `names()` of the `data.frame` I want to write to my Excel file):

```
require(tidyxl)
colnames <- c("Item","Score","Mean")
excelfile <- "FormattedSheet.xlsx"
x <- xlsx_cells(excelfile)

  # Find all cells with character values: return their address (i.e., Cell) and character (i.e., Value)
  chars <- x[x$data_type == "character", c("address", "character")]

  starting.positions <- unlist(
    chars[which(chars$character %in% colnames), "address"]
  )
     # returns: c(C6, D6, E6)
```