# Apply Excel Styling Across Multiple Spreadsheets using openxlsx in R?

Tags: r, excel, lapply, purrr, openxlsx

I have an example where I write multiple individual spreadsheets, I would like to style each spreadsheet but expanding the column width, formatting it as a table, and making the header background blue:

**Creation of Multiple Spreadsheets on Parameter Date**

```
df <- data.frame(Date = Sys.Date() - 0:4, Logical = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE),
                 Currency = paste("$", -2:2), Accounting = -2:2, hLink = "https://CRAN.R-project.org/",
                 Percentage = seq(-1, 1, length.out = 5), TinyNumber = runif(5)/1e+09, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

dat_grouped <- df %>% group_by(Date)


lapply(group_split(dat_grouped), function(x){openxlsx::write.xlsx(x, paste0(x$Date[1], ".xlsx"))})
```

**How can I Apply Styling to Each Individual Spreadsheet - Example of Ideal Output**

[image]

[image]

Where the header is light blue and columns are widened.

Comment: pg 6 https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/openxlsx/openxlsx.pdf

Comment: thanks, I reviewed the documentation and that part is clear but I am unsure how to apply the logic when I am sing lapply

Comment: Why not set up one workbook with all the formatting then use that as a template?

Comment: could you possibly share an example with the code and data I provided above please?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11228942/write-from-r-into-template-in-excel-while-preserving-formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be enough to get you started. Note: I changed the `Currency` variable, keeping it as numeric. When you paste "$" it becomes text. Also, I split the data frame using `split` instead of `group_split`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(openxlsx)
library(purrr)

df <- data.frame(Date = Sys.Date() - 0:4, Logical = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE),
                 Currency = -2:2, Accounting = -2:2, hLink = "https://CRAN.R-project.org/",
                 Percentage = seq(-1, 1, length.out = 5), TinyNumber = runif(5)/1e+09, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

dat_grouped <- df %>% split(~ Date)


# Create styles for each format you need
blue_white <- createStyle(fgFill = "#03a9f4", fontColour = "white")
pct <- createStyle(numFmt = "PERCENTAGE")
currency <- createStyle(numFmt = "CURRENCY")
round2 <- createStyle(numFmt = "0.000000000")

wb <- write.xlsx(dat_grouped, "output.xlsx")
sheets <- seq_along(dat_grouped)

# Apply formatting
walk2(sheets, dat_grouped, ~ addStyle(wb, .x, pct, cols = 6, rows = 2:nrow(.y)))
walk2(sheets, dat_grouped, ~ addStyle(wb, .x, currency, cols = 3, rows = 2:nrow(.y)))
walk2(sheets, dat_grouped, ~ addStyle(wb, .x, round2, cols = 7, rows = 2:nrow(.y)))
walk(sheets, ~ addStyle(wb, .x, blue_white, row = 1, cols = seq_len(ncol(df))))
walk(sheets, ~ setColWidths(wb, .x, cols = seq_len(ncol(df)), widths = "auto"))
saveWorkbook(wb, "output.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With `openxlsx2` a possible solution would be the following using table styles and `wb_clone_sheet_style()` (this is helpful if you want to clone complicated styles from one sheet on another sheet):

```r
library(openxlsx2)

df <- data.frame(
  Date = Sys.Date() - 0:4, 
  Logical = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE),
  Currency = paste("$", -2:2),
  Accounting = -2:2,
  hLink = "https://CRAN.R-project.org/",
  Percentage = seq(-1, 1, length.out = 5), 
  TinyNumber = runif(5)/1e+09,
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

dat_grouped <- df %>% dplyr::group_by(Date)

wb <- wb_workbook()$
  # first worksheet
  add_worksheet("1st")$
  add_data_table(x = dat_grouped, 
                 table_style = "TableStyleLight13")$
  set_col_widths(cols = "A:G", widths = c(10, 10, 10, 10, 25, 10, 10))$
  # second worksheet
  add_worksheet("2nd")$
  add_data_table(x = dat_grouped, 
                 table_style = "TableStyleLight13")$
  clone_sheet_style(from = "1st", to = "2nd")
  
if (interactive()) wb$open()
```

[image]